# PHP - Office365 connecting with imap_open

Tags: php, office365, imap-open

thanks for the anticipated help.

Does anyone know the current state of php connecting to office365 using imap_open?

I have tried all the suggestions found on stack overflow and my current code is below. I simply cant seem to connect to office365 using imap_open, either straight connection failure or other erros below.

Does anyone have this working in 2022

I have tried the code below which results in the error below. I have also gone through the office365 admin panel and whitelisted my server IP, i have enabled SMTP auth and enabled IMAP on the account I'm connecting to.

```
$username = 'xxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxx';

$host = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox";
$mbox=imap_open($host,$username,$password, NULL, 1, 
                           array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN')) or 
                   die(var_dump(imap_errors()));
```

This gives me the current error of too many login failures, but this error changes bases on the settings i try above within imap_open so im not sure this is an actual true error code

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox in imap.connect2.php on line 14 array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "LOGIN failed." [1]=> string(23) "Too many login failures" }

So if i change the code to something more simple without the DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR additional, i still get an error. See code and error below

```
$mbox=imap_open($host,$username,$password) or 
                   die(var_dump(imap_errors()));
```

I get authenticate failed

> **Warning**: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}Inbox in **/home/tnslive/domains/manage.tnslive.com/public_html/webmail/imap.connect2.php** on line **13**
> array(3) { [0]=> string(56) "Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed." [1]=> string(56) "Retrying PLAIN authentication after AUTHENTICATE failed." [2]=> string(57) "Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed." }

I've been trying this for a week and tried other slight alternatives with the domain used in the imap_open function for office365 .... im at a massive loss here and i've bought office365 for a lot of people and now we cant use our application with the primary email via our php software. Nightmare.

Comment: does the server use a `self-signed` certificate?

Comment: Hi there, no the server uses a letsencrypt cert

Comment: I just wondered about the `novalidate-cert` portion of the uri - which is typically used for `self-signed` certificates

Comment: Did you solve this one yet? I am also facing this problem

Comment: Related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72304655/outlook-login-failed-while-connecting-through-node-imap

Comment: Does anyone know when this began to happen? If we all encountered it on the same date then it would indicate a change at Microsoft. My issue began at 2022-06-22 00:00 UTC.

Comment: I changed my script to connect a little less frequently, and after 10 hours it began to work again. 

Answer (score 0):

This code works since 2018 still (on a production server)

```php
$host = $mailboxes[$mailbox]['host'];
$enc = '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert';
$this->mailbox = "{" . $host . $enc . "}";
imap_open($this->mailbox, $config['username'], $config['password'], 1, 0, array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'GSSAPI'));
```

Although I should mention 2 more things.

1. `outlook.office365.com` sometimes resolves to IPv6, but php doesn't work well with IPv6, so you will need to resolve `outlook.office365.com` IPv4 manually somehow (personally I have a pre-defined array with IPs and get a random index from the array each time).
2. You should enable AUTHENTICATE PLAIN method (see [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-september-2021-update/ba-p/2772210)) <-- I think it's the thing you want.